# Creating a picture tap based app in Ionic or meteor?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework

Suppose In an App there is a pic of a hand which shows five fingers.
If anybody tap on any one of the finger then suddenly a pop up will come
and some data will be send to the server.

Is this possible with Ionic or meteor especially the tap feature on a picture(not a button) and then a popup?

Update: I figured out that it is possible through d3.js but still how to connect those fingers to dots of d3.
Is there a possibility of such app in Ionic or meteor?

Comment: Ha it is possible in Ionic framework but we have to implement

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to be implemented very simply with the use of an image map.

First create your template

```
<template name="handClick">
  <img src="hand.gif" width="xxx" height="xxx" usemap="#handmap">

  <map name="planetmap">
    <area id="thumb" shape="circle" coords="x,x,x" href="#">
    <area id="index" shape="circle" coords="x,x,x" href="#">
    <area id="middle" shape="circle" coords="x,x,x" href="#">
    <area id="ring" shape="circle" coords="x,x,x" href="#">
    <area id="pinky" shape="circle" coords="x,x,x" href="#">
  </map>
</template>
```

Then your event listeners

```
Template.handClick.events({
  "click area": function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    //handle click on any area element in the template
  },
  "click #thumb": function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //handle click on the #thumb area element
  }
});
```